# Using migrations to add a column to a database table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

i'm having problem when i add new column i typed 
rails g migration AddCustomToUser and wrote:

```
add_column :users, :first_name, :string
add_column :users, :last_name, :string
add_column :users, :address, :text
add_column :users, :DOB, :date
add_column :users, :gender, :string
```

and type: 
rake db:migrate

i went to sign up page and i made

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :username, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it run ok but when i go to rails c it shows me nail
first_name: nil, last_name: nil, address: nil, DOB: nil, gender: nil>

and help

Comment: Did you try to restart your server?

Comment: You should post your complete form along with relevant controller code . It seems as if your data is not getting saved properly!

Comment: yes i did but still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters through strong parameters and then try to run .

[strong parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)

.Also you need to check create method in controller but before that you should check on console first try inserting the values and then check whether it is getting saved or not.If not then find the errors by @variable.errors.full_messages? It will tell you the error .And also keep in mind if you do any changes in model so in console it will only be reflected it you do reload!

Comment: it works buddy i forgot to add them to registration_params